# Why doesn't Django template show data correctly?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm a new Django programmer and I'm writing a learning app.  This app have a foreign key  relations and I use prefetch_related method.  This system runs well ;-)

My problem is at the template, when I show the data from the table, the browser shows this menssages:

ID Bill number                   Warehouse       Article                    Quantity  Price (<<-- columns)
1 CabeceraDeFacturas object (1) Primer almacén  Bolsa plástico .05 mm. KK.  10      1
...

The questions are:
¿Why does show the message "CabeceraDeFacturas object (1)" instead of a bill number?
¿Can I fix this? ¿How?

The information about is:

Part of models.py

```
class CabeceraDeFacturas(models.Model):
    ID_cliente = models.ForeignKey('Clientes',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_factura = models.DateField('Fecha de factura: ')
    ID_formaDePago = models.ForeignKey('FormasDePago',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Porcentaje_IVA = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=21)
    Total_factura = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
    
    
    #def __str__(self):
     #   return self.id
    
class LineasDeFacturacion(models.Model):
    ID_factura = models.ForeignKey('CabeceraDeFacturas',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ID_almacen = models.ForeignKey('Almacen',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ID_articulo = models.ForeignKey('Articulos',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    Precio = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        default_related_name = 'lineas'
    
    # def __str__(self):
    #    return str(self.ID_factura)
```

Part of views.py

```
class VerFacturaCompleta(ListView):
    #model = CabeceraDeFacturas
    model = LineasDeFacturacion
    template_name = "ListarTodasLasFacturasConLineas.html"
    # recuperar las facturas completas y líneas --> comprobar
    # queryset = CabeceraDeFacturas.objects.all().select_related('lineas')
    queryset = LineasDeFacturacion.objects.all().prefetch_related('ID_factura')
    
    paginate_by = 10
```

And finally, the template:

```
<h1>Listar facturas</h1>
   
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Factura</th>
              <th scope ="col">Almacén</th>
              <th scope ="col">Artículo</th>
              <th scope ="col">Cantidad</th>
              <th scope="col">Precio</th>
              <!--<th scope="col">Almacén</th>-->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for articulo in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <!--<th scope="row"><a href= "{{ articulo.pk }}">{{ articulo.pk }}</a></th>-->
                <th scope ="row"> {{ articulo.pk }} </th>
                <td>{{ articulo.ID_factura }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.ID_almacen }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.ID_articulo }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.cantidad }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.Precio }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
<hr>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you give more details of your template context "articulo"?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow community. Please make sure to include your complete code so that people can provide a good answer to your problem. Currently your `view` code, `views.py` is incomplete, we can't see what is passed as the context. Include the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the **template** only uses "object_list".  This object_list comes form a instruction like this "queryset = LineasDeFacturacion.objects.all().prefetch_related('ID_factura')"; which is in a view.

The view which I use for this template is the next:

```
class VerFacturaCompleta(ListView):
    #model = CabeceraDeFacturas
    model = LineasDeFacturacion
    template_name = "ListarTodasLasFacturasConLineas.html"
    # recuperar las facturas completas y líneas --> comprobar
    # queryset = CabeceraDeFacturas.objects.all().select_related('lineas')
    queryset = LineasDeFacturacion.objects.all().prefetch_related('ID_factura')
    paginate_by = 10
```

I don't use a context inside the view, only, the view pass an object_list (queryset) to the template.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake.  The problem was in the models.py declaration.  The CabeceraDeFactura class didn't had a data return. When I fixed this mistake

```
def __str__(self):
       return str(self.id)
```

the template shows the data correctly.

Thanks for your time!